# How to fix Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1?

Tags: c, xcode, exit, clang

Hi there I am new to C programming and have been using Xcode to write my simple CS HW.  They have been working fine until a couple weeks ago when I keep getting this error code below.  I went ahead and try to run some old programs that I know for sure works but still get this error.  I looked everywhere and can't find the solution.  If you have a solution please help.  Although I would love a specific answer, I am very new to this and would hope you take that into consideration when explaining.  Thank you very much.

```
Ld /Users/------/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gehcspqxloqgaahbdyjslulobzys/Build/Products/Debug/Test normal x86_64
    cd /Users/------/Desktop/Test
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.7
    /Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk -L/Users/------/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gehcspqxloqgaahbdyjslulobzys/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/------/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gehcspqxloqgaahbdyjslulobzys/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/------/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gehcspqxloqgaahbdyjslulobzys/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Test.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -o /Users/------/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gehcspqxloqgaahbdyjslulobzys/Build/Products/Debug/Test

ld: duplicate symbol _main in /Users/------/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gehcspqxloqgaahbdyjslulobzys/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HW4.o and /Users/------/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-gehcspqxloqgaahbdyjslulobzys/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug/Test.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/HW3.o for architecture x86_64
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

what is this error code?

```
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Stop using Xcode.  It introduces a layer of confusion that you do not need.  Learning to build executables from the command line is an important skill, and is not difficult.  Open a shell and compile with gcc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ld: duplicate symbol _main

This means that you have two main functions inside the same project. Considering the names of your .o files (HW4.o and HW3.o) I am guessing that you are trying to compile two projects at the same time and are somehow linking them, thus having two main functions.

Comment: Thank you NickLH, great help!